# Rendering same Google Map twice on one page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I'm working on a Rails app that uses CSS 'tabs' to separate a form. I need to render the same google map in two of the tabs, but the map is only being appended to the first `#map_canvas` div. What I have currently:

```
# form.html.erb

<div class='tabs'>
  <div id='tab1'>
    <div class="map container">
      <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='tab2'>
    <div class="map container">
      <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

# map.js

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
```

My first attempt was to render the map in a partial, and reference that twice, but it had the same effect.

Is there a way to do this properly?

Answer (score 2):

An id should be unique within a page,  you have used 'map_canvas' twice in the page. Instead of using Id you can try with class

```
 <div class='tabs'>
  <div id='tab1'>
    <div class="map container">
      <div class="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='tab2'>
    <div class="map container">
      <div class="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

#js
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
```

Comment: Just to add to this, a partial is the right way to go: pass through a local variable which will allow you to set a unique id for each one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='tabs'>
  <div id='tab1'>
    <div class="map container">
      <div class="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='tab2'>
    <div class="map container">
      <div class="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## map.js

```
map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName("map_canvas")[0],mapOptions);
map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName("map_canvas")[1],mapOptions);
```